# Android, connection timeout when making request from device to local server

Tags: java, android, flutter, android-studio

I have read many posts related to this one, but none of them seem to provide a solution to my problem.

I am trying to reach my localhost server from my android app on a physical device, but keep getting a connection timeout.

I can ping the server from the device, and visa versa, I can reach the endpoint in the browser from both the device and the development machine, but I can not reach it from inside my app. The internet permissions are set in the manifest file.

Using the emulator, and setting the endpoint to `10.0.2.2:3000` to reach it just fine, but if I set it to my machines local IP `192.168.1.129:3000` and run it on the physical device, then it times out.

Both the device and the server are set to static IP addresses.

I'm running out of things to check with my limited knowledge of networking. It was working fine the other day, but I had to change my network settings and firewall settings around for something else, and can't seem to troubleshoot the issue here.

If anyone could help me troubleshoot this, it would be greatly appreciated.

edit: Thought I should say that the port is forwarded on the router, in case that helps troubleshooting.

edit2: I've also tried disabling my firewall completely to see if it was a firewall issue.

Comment: You did not tell what kind of server you have runing.

Comment: You do not have to forward ports if you are in a local network.

Comment: @greenapps it's just a simple node express server.

Comment: Any protocol used?

Comment: @greenapps I'm not 100% what you mean by protocol, but it's just a real basic express server, no https or anything like that...

Comment: So no http:// ?

Comment: @greenapps Hmm, I wasn't aware you could do without `http://`. I'm using OKHttp inside my android app, and it threw an error the first time I tried entering in the address without `http://`. So my endpoint looks like `http://192.168.1.129:3000`

Comment: So the used server is a webserver (using http:// protocol). And using a browser on your device you obtain the requested page? Indeed using okhttp your url should always start with http://.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167928/discussion-between-dustin-and-greenapps).

Comment: No. No chat. Just answer my question.

Comment: @greenapps. It's a web server using the express js framework. On the android device, I am able to retrieve the JSON. If I swap the url to http://10.0.2.2:3000 and use the emulator, I can reach it just fine. But on the device, using http://192.168.1.129:3000 results in a timeout.

Comment: `On the android device, I am able to retrieve the JSON.` It is unclear to me what you are doing to obtain that result. My simple question was `And using a browser on your device you obtain the requested page?`. Please answer to the point.

Comment: My bad it's late here. Yes, navigating to the server in the browser on the device, I can get the JSON.

Comment: Well then there is no reason that your app should not work from that device. Isnt there a default page you have to specify too like `http://192.168.1.129:3000/index` or so?

Comment: That is what I thought. I figured since I can ping the machine, and access the server from the browser inside the device, I should be able to access it in the app. In the server I'm just returning some JSON from a `POST` request at the moment.

Comment: How are you executing a post request with the browser on your device?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not. In the app I am issuing a `POST` request. In the app, I am issuing a GET request which was originally just a quick way to test if the server was working at all during initial setup that I just haven't deleted yet and keep reusing for quick testing. It is returning the same type of response object though as the post.

Answer (score 1):

To run your local server in different devices:

1. Android Emulator: 10.0.2.2:3000 (or any other port if you have configured)
2. IOS emulator: localhost:3000
3. Android/IOS external device: your-pc-IP-address:3000

To find your IP address in Windows:

1. Open cmd
2. run "ipconfig /all" command
3. Under "Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi" section. Find IPv4 address. Use that IP address to run your application.

NOTE: There are more than one IPv4 addresses available in output. So, make sure you use the one mentioned in point 3.

Comment: Man... it did work fine (Android Emulator: 10.0.2.2 - but using the 4000 port on my GraphQL test project). Cheers!